# Subclass a Struct or Similar

Tags: swift, generics, struct, subclassing

I understand how structs and classes (and protocols) work on the basic level. I have a rather common situation:

I need to have generic value types with operators which really must copy on assignment.
These types have complex structure and I would like to be able to specialise by subclassing otherwise there will be copied code everywhere and it will be poor programming.

I have tried protocols and extensions but then because the protocol wasn't generic I was unable to define the (generic) operators I wanted.
If I use classes I will not copy on assignment.

Today's example is I have Matrix, and SquareMatrix under that with specific square matrix functions. There are operators and the matrices can be populated by anything conforming to my ring protocol. I tried defining almost all the functionality in a protocol with associated type, and an extension.

Edit: I am really wondering what I should be coding. In the matrix situation I need to be able to pass a square matrix as any other, so subclassing is the only option? Maybe I'm wrong. The main issue is when I have to write a function which talks about internal values, I have to know the generic type argument to do anything useful. For example when defining addition, I have to create a new matrix and declare its generic type, but where do I get that from when I only know something is a (nongeneric) protocol - it's real type is generic but despite the protocol having this associated type, I have no way of getting it out.

**Solution** thanks to alexander momchliov. Essentially more work was needed to move code into the protocol extension fully and use 'Self' for all the relevant types. In the extension the compiler was happy with what the generic types were.

The code was private, I am sorry I was unable to paste any during this question. Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: Post code what you have tried and what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Struct inheritance/polymorphism wouldn't be possible for at least 2 reasons (that I can think of).

1. Structs are stored and moved around by value. This requires the compiler to know, at compile time, the exact size of the struct, in order to know how many bytes to copy after the start of a struct instance.

   Suppose there was a struct `A`, and a struct `B` that inherits from `A`. Whenever the compiler sees a variable of type `A`, it has no way to be sure if the runtime type will really be an `A`, or if `B` was used instead. If `B` added on new stored properties that `A` didn't have, then `B`'s size would be different (bigger) than `A`. The compiler would be unable to determine the runtime type, and the size of these structs.
2. Polymorphism would require a function table. A function table would be stored as a static member of the struct type. But to access this static member, every struct instance would need an instance member which encodes the type of the instance. This is usually called the "isa" pointer (as in, this instance **is a** `A` type). This would be 8 bytes of overhead (on 64 bit systems) for every instance. Considering `Int`, `Bool`, `Double`, and many other common types are all implemented as structs, this would be an unacceptable amount of overhead. Just think, a `Bool` is a one byte value, which would need 8 bytes of overhead. That's 11% efficiency!

For these reasons, protocols play a huge part in Swift, because they allow you introduce inheritance-like behaviour, without these issues.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I mostly knew this already. My structs are pretty big so overhead isn't an issue.
Now I think about it on this occasion I will just have to put up with classes because I simply need one type to have more functionality but also occasionally pretend it is the simpler version. Sigh, no value types for me today.
I will amend my question to aim for "what is the best policy".

Comment: @Richard Birkett Declare a protocol Matrix, Add default behavior in extension, Then your Struct SquareMatrix can be a Matrix with additional behavior. Value Types confirming to protocol !

Comment: You don't need to use classes, as @Irfan suggested, just contain all the functionality in a protocol's extension, and have your structs conform to it

Comment: See edit. Generics with functions that accept both are the problem.

Comment: @RichardBirkett I'm not sure what your issue is, without actually seeing your code. You can just define addition as an extension of the protocol. There's no need for generics, or specifying a concrete type

Comment: I'm unable to paste my code directly but it just doesn't work because the inputs have nongeneric type, then the function code needs to know those types.

Comment: "t just doesn't work because the inputs have nongeneric type, then the function code needs to know those types" wut?

Comment: How do you expect me to help you?

Comment: I apologise, I'll be clearer. Suppose MProto is the protocol. It has associated type T. It declares a tonne of generic functions in the extension using <T>. In my operator I need to call one of the functions, but the arguments of the operator have nongeneric type MProto. So then when I call one of these generic functions with argument of type MProto, the compiler tells me I'm wrong because my arguments aren't generic. I think in this case it's the receiver more than the argument but the principle is identical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130357/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-richard-birkett).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in swift the protocol can be generic if you will use `associatedtype`.

On the over hand, you need the Value Semantics, so you can use `Copy on Write` methodology. This will give the value semantic to your classes (so they will be as safe as structs).

This both ways can be used to solve your problem.